# Some related questions about DNA differences in a single organism

Tags: genetics, dna

1. If you took a DNA sample from someone's brain and that same persons liver at more or less the same time, would that DNA - all else being equal (e.g. no mutations from radiation) - be *exactly the same?*
2. If you took a DNA sample from an embryo, and then that embryo went on to be born, live a long life for 80 years and become an old man/woman; if you were to then take another DNA sample of this person, would that sample be *exactly the same* as the one which you took when he/she was in the womb? (again, all things being equal - so dismissing mutations due to radiation for example).

Comment: I don't have much of a scientific background, and am seeking your expertise so that I can consider it's relevance for both the buddhist doctrine of impermanence and christian convictions about souls, personhood, abortion etc.

Comment: What do you mean by 'exactly the same'? You should be more specific. You could be talking about the same genes, the same variants, the same heterochromatin configuration, 3-d structure, number of repeats, duplications ....

Comment: In addition to the above, what do you mean by "no mutations from radiation etc"? Do you understand that mutations accumulate due to errors in DNA replication?

Answer (score 2):

No. even if you exclude the changes in DNA sequences that originate from mismatch errors in DNA replication, mutation etc.
Because

1.As a person gets old , the short repeat sequences in the telomere of a chromosome  in each cell may be lost or be reduced in amounts leading to a sequence difference.Moreover this changes in telomere sequences may cause cancer/cell apoptosis .
[Telomere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere)

2.Do not forget transposons (consisted of DNA transposons and retrotransposons). They change their position in genome and multiply their DNA over time.So they also lead to sequence differences in a person(comparing his/her younger and older DNA)
[Transposons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposable_element)
These were the answers to question 2 .You can also think that there might be a slight difference in DNA of two different tissue of the same individual (because of the tolemere and transposons)

As a zygote starts to multiply itself ,slight changes of sequence will happen to the offspring cells .After a dozens of cell division you may encounter a little deviation compared to the original zygote sequence.

Comment: +1, but it might help to cite the [mutation rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_rate#Variation_in_mutation_rates), or at the very least something else.  An overall sense of the *scale* of the mutation variation within an organism would improve this answer

Comment: shorter telomeres is one reason dolly died so young, she was cloned from differentiated somatic cells, so she started with shorter telomeres.